# Python - Streaming data from file to asyncio-enabled Kinesis Producer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working with an asyncio-enabled Kinesis Producer module in Python 3.6 to be deployed to AWS Lambda (so I need this to be 3.6 compatible).

My use-case is to lazy-read a file (roughly 100MB compressed - 1GB uncompressed) from disk and stream the data (500 lines at a time) to the Kinesis Producer.  I want the Kinesis Producer to start pushing the 500 records out to Kinesis while I'm reading in the next batch of 500 lines.

What I'm noticing is that it reads the entire file in, 500 lines at a time, and then starts pushing the data out to the Kinesis Producer.  And it appears the reason is because I'm not calling `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, but I also don't know if I'm doing this in the right way.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Extract filename from event and download file from S3
    event_loop.run_until_complete(process(filename))
    pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending))


async def process(filename):
    for chunk in read_lines(filename, MAX_RECORDS_IN_BATCH):
    asyncio.ensure_future(write_kinesis(chunk)).add_done_callback(callback)


def callback(result):
    print(str(result))


async def write_kinesis(records):
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(producer.put_records(records=records))
```

If I add `await asyncio.sleep(.1)` to the end of the `process(filename)` function, than it seems to do exactly what I want, though of course, it's then actually blocking the main thread for that .1 second.

**Q- Is that the trick, block with the asyncio.sleep for just long enough for the Kinesis Producer to push the data out?  The less it sleeps, the more data I hold in memory because the kinesis client won't have as much time to push the data out, but it will run faster (up to a point)?**

**Q- Am I doing this the right way?  Again, I'm trying to read 500 lines, push to kinesis (asynchronously), read another 500 while the Kinesis client is working, rinse and repeat.**

Additionally, when looking at the print statement from the callback function, I noticed that if the write_kinesis function does not return anything, the callback's print statement has `result=None`, whereas if the write_kinesis function returns the Future, the callback's print statement has `result=<Task pending...11b35f18>()`.

**Q- I assume without the return statement, there is no result, however why is it calling the callback function when the status is still "Pending"?**

**EDIT 1:** I forgot to mention, the Kinesis client is already asyncio-enabled.

Comment: What exactly is the question? I'd edit it but it is probably better if you clarify :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry...they were buried within a lot of text.  See changes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just call async functions with await

```
async def process(filename):
    for chunk in read_lines(filename, MAX_RECORDS_IN_BATCH):
        await producer.put_records(records=chunk)

async def run():
    # Extract filename from event and download file from S3
    await process(filename)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete( run() )
loop.close()
```

Comment: The read_lines may be sync here - aiofiles does async reading of files OP

Comment: Well...I don't know why it wasn't working the first time I (thought I) tried it this way, but simply awaiting the producer call does work.  That said, for some reason unknown for me, it is about half as fast as wrapping the producer call in asyncio.ensure_future with an await asyncio.sleep(.05) after it.  But, that's outside the scope of this particular question...

Comment: Interesting.  You don't have to await on each chunk from read_lines.  You can just do temp_list.append( producer.put_records() ) then asyncio.gather to wait on all the chunks after kicking them all off.